# What is the best way to use an on screen keyboard in a large application with Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on a large scale Vue js application that has many screens and many inputs and is displayed on a touch screen monitor. I am looking for the best way to create a custom keyboard component that takes input and computes things like max and min values and outputs the value to the input that was selected accordingly. I am wondering where the best place to put this keyboard is, what plugin to use for the keyboard, and how to handle the input events.

Comment: What is the OS behind the screen? I would try to find the setting in the OS to show the keyboard when user enters input. For example. for [windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/make-windows-10-show-touch-keyboard-automatically)

Comment: Its windows 10, but I'm looking to make a more custom keyboard rather than using their default one

Comment: Then maybe something like [vue-touch-keyboard](https://github.com/icebob/vue-touch-keyboard)